# warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/andy in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: bash

This script is no longer working??

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate
#    
# REQUIRES THAT RUBY BE INSTALLED AND THAT VOL BE IN THE PATH !!
# See notes in vol !!
volume.rb 40
```

I get this when running it:

```
/home/andy/bin/volume.rb:62: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/andy in PATH, mode 040777
Current status

ID D M Vol Sink Name Output
0. no 39% pci-0000_00_01.1 hdmi-stereo
1. no 0% usb-Microsoft_Microsoft___LifeCam_HD-5000-02 analog-mono
2. * no 19% pci-0000_00_14.2 analog-stereo
```

I ran `chmod o-w /home/andy` and the script ran properly.

However, I would like to know what caused the problem so maybe I could avoid a future problem.

Comment: Most likely *something* you did somewhere set your home directory to have world-writable permissions (you didn't run `chmod 777` on your home directory did you?).  That caused some insecure directory warnings.

Comment: I did not run any chmod. I very rarely use that command.

Comment: Problem has come back. :-(  andyk_~/bin$ 40_VOL.sh
##Current status###########################################################
ID D  M  Vol Sink Name                                      Output
0.   no 39% pci-0000_00_01.1                              hdmi-stereo 
1.   no 0% usb-Microsoft_Microsoft___LifeCam_HD-5000-02  analog-mono 
2. * no 59% pci-0000_00_14.2                              analog-stereo 
And chmod o-w /home/andy no longer works.

Comment: without knowing the specific cause, it's impossible to give you guidance... my only guess is that `volume.rb` might be adjusting your permissions, but there's no way to determine that just from this post.

Comment: volume.rb is not adjusting permissions as I have been using it for several years and I have not changed it. If there is an alternative, I am game.